# How to get optional certificate in openssl

Tags: openssl

I used openssl to create SMIME.

i have a valid certificate.I tried to parse this certificate using the following function

```
int PKCS12_parse(PKCS12 *p12, const char *pass, EVP_PKEY **pkey, X509 **cert, STACK_OF(X509) **ca);
```

The certificate parsed successfully and i could able get `pkey` , `cert` values.But `ca` always comes out with `null`.

How to get this `STACK_OF(X509)` value from a certificate. I want to use this `STACK_OF(X509)` value in `PKCS7_sign` function.

Answer (score 2):

If `ca` comes out as `NULL`, then you probably have no additional certificates in your PKCS12 structure.  You do not necessarily *need* any additional certificates - if your certificate is signed directly by a CA certificate already known to the recipient, then you can simply supply `certs = NULL` to `pkcs7_sign()` and no additional certificates will be included in the signed message.